# How to get installed apps list with Unity3D?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an android launcher with Unity3D in C#, Everything is in place except detection of installed apps.

I have tried a lot of different things, but they all get stuck at the same place, accessing `getInstalledApplications` in the **PackageManager**.

I think I have managed to replicate the `ApplicationInfo` class in C#, at least variable storage wise, by studying the android source, so I don't think that's a problem, at least not yet...

Simply put, I need the URI (or something I can use to open the app), the  name of the app, and the icon of the app (either a string to its location, or the `Texture2D` itself), I try for `ApplicationInfo` because it has all that and then some, but if I have to get them individually or through another method, that's totally fine.

Here is an example of what I am doing now.
This happens regardless of whether I use a Class or an Object.

```
void Start () {
                AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.pm.PackageManager");

            AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        Debug.Log(currentActivity.Call<string>("getPackageName"));
        int flag = pluginClass.GetStatic<int>("GET_META_DATA");
        AndroidJavaClass syspackage = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaClass>("getPackageManager");
```

And here's the error I get

```
AndroidJavaException: Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name = 'getInstalledApplications' signature=Ljava/lang/Class;' in class Lcom.unity3d/player/UnityPlayerActivity;
```

How do I make this work? Or can you tell/show me another method that will accomplish the goal?

**//EDIT**
Okay I messed with this for HOURS trying every possible combination, and I got it.

```
AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.pm.PackageManager");
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
int flag = pluginClass.GetStatic<int>("GET_META_DATA");
AndroidJavaObject pm = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
AndroidJavaObject syspackages = pm.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstalledApplications", flag);
```

Now I just gotta figure out how to get the strings and ints i need out of the Java object and into C# strings and ints which is a totally different problem than this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a string as the param for getInstalledApplications instead of an integer.

You need to get your hands on an instance of **PackageManager**, to do this you'll need to get an **Activity**, fortunately, Unity can give you that.

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

AndroidJavaObject packageManager = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");

int flag = pluginClass.GetStatic<int>("GET_META_DATA");

AndroidJavaObject[] arrayOfAppInfo = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject[]>("getInstalledApplications", flag);
```

Comment: Good point, that fixes a problem I didn't see coming.
But it doesn't fix the error I mentioned.

Comment: That seems to work, however now I get the error `Exception: JNI: unknown signature type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[ApplicationInfo]' (obj = System.Collections.Generic.List'1[ApplicationInfo] equal`<br/> I'm guessing that means I didn't make the Application Info class properly? Or is this a new issue?

Comment: You can't mirror a Java class on the Unity side. You'll always be working with AndroidJavaObject. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Well that fixes that, good to know, and honestly that's a lot easier too. But, a new error has appeared yet again, I'm sorry this must be turning out to be such a bother for you. `AndroidJavaException: Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name = 'getInstalledApplications' signature=(I)[Ljava/lang/Object;' in class Landroid/app/ApplicationPackageManager;`

Comment: Still haven't figured out the answer to this issue. I marked your answer as accepted because I highly doubt I'm getting anyone else's help on this, and you at least gave it a good try. Spent all day on the internet and no one else is trying to do this apparently, so I'm probably just stuck at this.     I think the issue is that it's getting the package manager from the app rather than from system.

Comment: has that method on your object explicitly been made/marked visible to Unity ?