# Open an android app of your phone by gazing at it with the cardboard sdk,and unity

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a cardboard app with unity.
I found this sample app on github https://github.com/CJ-Davies/Cardboard_get-started-menu (credits on him).

[You move your head and the gaze controled pointer changes the color of the cubes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGJcP.png)
but my question is how can I achieve to instead of changing the color of the cube, to open any app installed on the mobile phone, so it's like an menu.

Comment: As a beginner (we all are someway), you should focus on more easy tasks.
Today, the more comfortable way to learn seems to be the tutorials. Such a project will need month of work, or at least month of learning. Perseverance will be the main quality you will need.
Notice that the project you work on is not achieved, possibly not working.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when asking a question we post what we have tried, potentially some code and results.

Now though from your question it looks like you are largely looking for a list of the apps, and likely a ability to open them.  And it looks like you already have your cube and on click effect, so you largely need the list I imagine.

Googling around I could find a couple of resources, [How to get installed apps list with Unity3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155974/how-to-get-installed-apps-list-with-unity3d) helps you to figure out how to get a list from the package manager.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/627703/detect-if-app-is-installed-on-android.html helps you to figure how to launch the list while having the package manager class.

These same actions to be done in android studio can be found at [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) and [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android) respectively.

Hope this helps a bit in your goal.